# When I move arm in person, the skin penetrates through the clothes. How to make the clothes stay still?

Tags: rigging

[image: My image before I move the left upper arm]

[image: This is after]

How to we make clothes so that the clothes don't stretch like this? The skin always goes through the clothes.

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SOQWmbEQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/SOQWmbEQ/)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to sort your armature and object (like disable the *Auto Keying* option of the *Timeline*, close the actions of all the objects in the *Dope Sheet*, switch your armature to rest pose, rotate it in *Object* mode so that it's vertical, apply rotation of your objects...). Then to correctly weight the jacket, give it a *Transfer Data* modifier, give it the body as *Source*, enable *Vertex Data* and click on *Vertex Groups*, click on *Generate Data Layers* and apply the modifier. The jacket has inherited of the weight of the body, it should move much better:

[image]

Comment: When I apply it is like this

Comment: The Jacket had changed its shape once I applied the modifier

Comment: How to make the shape stay the same?

Comment: Are you sure that your objects are clean? Have you respected all the steps in my answer? Or share your latest version

Comment: I don't get the part of switching your armature to rest pose

Comment: In Pose mode select everything and Alt R, Alt G

Comment: I did all the steps one by one but still doesn't work

Comment: Do I have to clear all keyframes before doing it?

Comment: Sure, as I say disable the Auto Keying option in the Timeline and close all the actions for all the objects

Comment: For some reason not just the jacket is impacted but the hair is too

Comment: I mean how do we make clothes not stretch that much when we rig our armatures

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, doesn't it work with the Data Transfer modifier? It worked fine for me... (some small corrections in Weight Paint mode probably)

Comment: This is a makehuman model, The clothes are already attached to the human so I am confused